# Photoshop Javascript - syntax error when trying to create new text layer

Tags: javascript, text, syntax, photoshop

I am trying to add a step to a script in Photoshop CC 2015 that will create a text layer and fill it with the text that I need (in the test case, "Test Text"). However, whenever I try to run the script in Photoshop, I get a syntax error pointing to the content line. I really have no clue what could be wrong.

Here is the step:

```
var newTextLayer = doc.artLayers.add();
newTextLayer.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
var text = newTextLayer.textItem;
text.contents = “TEST TEXT”
```

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is that you're using `“` instead of `"`. Try the latter: `text.contents = "TEST TEXT";`

Comment: @TAGraves Yes! That solved the problem! I had no clue that there was a difference. Thank you so much, I would have never caught that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"` or `'` instead of `“`.

`text.contents = "TEST TEXT";`